# Backend framework choices for React Native

Tags: android, react-native, server, client-server, backend

I want to develop an android app that is based on server-client system. I want to develop both backend and android client. It's 2020 and there has already many frameworks developed to provide server side missions to programs.

**My question is**

What are the trending backend technologies in android world (from database to REST API frameworks), with reasons? For now, I have 2 framework/library on my mind. Spring and Node.js. Google Firebase are also in that list.

**I also have another question**

Suppose that I made a backend project and want to deploy it on a real server (development made on localhost). What choices should be made ? 
For example, I made my development on Mysql and Springboot framework, should that server provide support for MySql and Java ? What is the procedure to deploy both database and backend application ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can develop web server using ExpressJs in Node, or using Django/Flask in Python, using golang, PHP Laravel or Codeignitor and many more. It all depends on which language you're already familiar with and which is the best for your use case. Frontend framework has very less to nothing to do with which back end to chose.

Answer to second question.
You can deploy your app in AWS, DigitalOcean, GCP etc. They'll provide VPS and other options to host your application and will make it accessible to outer world using IP or domain, however you configure it. You can install and self manage the DBs in the virtual system you have or you can use Managed database solutions provided by cloud platform, which has a pricing but is easier to manage.

PS: Both your questions were very broad and more of a opinion based answerable questions, it's better to ask these type of questions in platforms like Quora where you can get very detailed answers. Anyways, good luck with your project :)

Answer (score 5):

I have worked on these three stacks

1) React-Native Express API  MongoDb
2) React-Native Firebase
3) React_native Django

If you are comfortable with python and planning to create a large scale product, Django Backend could be a way to go. React_native Firebase is perfect for fast prototyping. If you are using a platform where you need to do heavy db query search, firebase data storage can be a poor choice.